# Непонимание работы триггеров

Tags: sql, sql-server

На удаление строки из табл. Suppliers должен среагировать триггер, если в табл. Supplies есть поставки от данного поставщика, и отменить удаление.

Данный код запрещает удалять не только поставщиков, которые ничего не поставляют, но и тех, кто имеет поставки.

```
CREATE TRIGGER SuppliersDeleteCondition
ON Suppliers
FOR DELETE
AS
IF NOT EXISTS (
               SELECT DISTINCT Srs.SupplierID
               FROM Suppliers Srs
               JOIN Supplies Ses
               ON Srs.SupplierID=Ses.SupplierID
               JOIN DELETED D
               ON D.SupplierID=Ses.SupplierID
              )
BEGIN
RAISERROR ('There are some supplies with this supplier', 16, 1)
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END;
```

А этот, наоборот, удаляет и тех, и этих:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SuppliersDeleteCondition
ON Suppliers
FOR DELETE
AS
IF NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT * 
           FROM DELETED D
           WHERE D.SupplierID IN (
                                  SELECT DISTINCT Srs.SupplierID
                                  FROM Suppliers Srs
                                  JOIN Supplies Ses
                                  ON Srs.SupplierID=Ses.SupplierID
                                 )
          )
BEGIN
RAISERROR ('There are some supplies with this supplier', 16, 1)
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END;
```

В чем проблема?
И какой параметр в данной ситуации уместней использовать FOR или INSTEAD OF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Триггера `INSTEAD OF` выполняются *вместо* действия для которого они написаны и тут абсолютно не подходят. А триггера *FOR* (синоним *AFTER*) выполняются *после* выполнения операции и по этому в момент вызова триггера в таблице `Suppliers` уже нет удаляемых записей. По этой причине использование в запросе проверки этой таблицы дает неверный результат. Вам надо упростить запрос проверки на наличие записей (И конечно проверять на наличие (*exists*), а не на отсутствие (*not exists*)):

```
CREATE TRIGGER SuppliersDeleteCondition
ON Suppliers
FOR DELETE
AS
IF EXISTS (
           SELECT 1
             FROM Supplies Ses
             JOIN DELETED D
               ON D.SupplierID=Ses.SupplierID
          )
BEGIN
  RAISERROR ('There are some supplies with this supplier', 16, 1)
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END;
```

P.S.:

- Не используйте слово `distinct` если оно не жизненно необходимо в запросе, оно замедляет работу. А при поиске наличия записей нам все равно уникальные или нет будут значения.
- То что делает ваш триггер автоматически сделал бы `FOREIGN KEY` на таблицу `Supplies` ссылающийся на ID из `Suppliers`
- Старайтесь не использовать лишних таблиц в запросах. Вы использовали в запросе таблицу `Suppliers` только ради того что бы взять из нее запись с ID=x и этот ID=x использовать в другой таблице, никакой логической нагрузки наличие таблицы не несло (только все портило).
- И не называйте, пожалуйста, *строки* рядками - люто режет глаз :)

Comment: Про FOREIGN KEY я знаю, но конкретно в этом примере нужно использовать триггеры.

Comment: Код который вы привели, позволяет удалить все строки. Насколько я понимаю, из-за параметра FOR. Но тогда получается, что предотвратить удаление триггером нельзя в принципе?

Comment: @salkcid А ошибка то, вызываемая raiserror появляется ? Вообще триггера для этого и предназначены.

Comment: Ошибка не появляется.

Comment: @salkcid Вот только что проверил. Создал таблицы с именами ваших таблиц. внес записи. создал триггер из ответа. При выполнении `delete from Suppliers where supplierID=1` появляется ошибка и удаление не происходит (при наличии записи supplierID=1 в таблице Supplies).

Comment: Странно. Приблизительная схема таблиц у меня: Suppliers(SupplierID,Name,Address), Supplies(SupplyID,SupplierID,ProductID,Weight,Price).

Comment: В чем, гипотетически, может быть проблема?

Comment: @salkcid В какой нибудь опечатке. Или триггер не пересоздался. Явно удалите триггер, после чего создайте его, скопировав из ответа. И удаляйте именно из Suppliers а не из какой нибудь другой таблицы (они у вас слишком похоже называются)

Comment: Опечаток, вроде бы, нету. Но за разъяснения большое спасибо. Буду искать в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: @salkcid В таких случаях я обычно коментарю вообще все условия, что бы триггер гарантированно создал ошибку и убеждаюсь что она есть. (что бы убедится что триггер создается и удаляю откуда надо). потом уже навешиваю условия.

Comment: Возможно такое, что проблема в том, что SupplierID в Supplies был внешним ключом ссылающимся на Suppliers? Создал полностью новою БД практически идентичную за исключением атрибутов foreign key и код заработал как нужно.

Comment: @salkcid Вам на английском SO уже ответили, что у вас проблема была в том, что у foreign key стояло "on delete cascade", при удалении записи из родительской таблицы он удалял записи в дочерней автоматически, до того как вызывал триггер. и триггер не находил ни одной строки